# Ionic: which third-party payment gateway

Tags: ionic-framework, payment

I see there is a Stripe integration already available for Ionic [here](http://market.ionic.io/starters/stripe-charge-with-checkout-nodejs-server), but is there something similar with a "third-party" payment service?

I think PayPal offers this, but is there a template for this?

Comment: None that I know of for ionic. Unless youre talking about Ionic v2, which has PayPal support. http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/paypal/

Comment: [mercado pago](https://github.com/mercadopago/px-hybrid) maybe this would help a bit.

Comment: @Louis have you checked Stripe. https://stripe.com  ? they handle all the credit card details, and they also have JavaScript library

Answer (score 1):

The template is still the same but you can create your own online payment using paypal service, also you can manage to secure the security of your payment template.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ionic-stripe-starter available on github](https://github.com/aaronksaunders/ionic-stripe-starter).

According to the README.md :

> This can ONLY be run on device and requires the following plugin and library :
>
> - [Telerik-Verified-Plugins/Stripe](https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/Stripe): Stripe is a payment infrastructure for the internet. Stripe Cordova SDK is built around the well organized REST API. it exposes a global window.stripe object that defines various operation to initialze and transfer payments
> - [angular-credit-cards](https://www.npmjs.org/package/creditcards): A set of Angular directives for constructing credit card payment forms